# Don't know where to start with this navigation bar (nav bar)

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav, navigationbar

I needed a nav bar. And i got really inspired from this website: http://hudyl.com/.

I'm not that good in html and css. So i don't know where to start, please help me!

Best regards.
Markus Harrison

Comment: SO is not a freelancing site

Comment: I know. But i have really tried anything!.. And i don't know what to do now. So i took the chance, and hopefully some awesome person will lead a new guy on the right tracks.

Comment: I'm sure there's a whole bunch of examples Google can find for you. Come back to SO when code you have doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="http://www.google.nl/">Menu item 1</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="http://www.google.nl/">Menu item 2</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="http://www.google.nl/">Menu item 3</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="http://www.google.nl/">Menu item 4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With the CSS of:

```
nav {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

And then style it to your needs.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/t8LhT/)**

Answer (score 0):

The site you refers to does use the concept of UL-LI to build the menu, but the actual CSS for styling (what you see as "movement") is a in the custom CSS Hadley.css.  Using the F12 Tools in IE (or most browsers), you can investigate what makes the menu tick.  Alternatively, look at the below links OR search for "CSS LI UL MENU transform html" to get many samples.

Sample:

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-flashy-menu-using-css/
```

Menu makers:

```
http://cssmenumaker.com/
http://html5-menu.com/html5-menu-maker.html
```